# How to do while not grep line from file in folder exists in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Given the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# var timeout = 5min.
while ( ! grep "Start" /var/log/azure/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.DockerExtension/{ver}/extension.log); do
    sleep 5
done

echo "hello world"
```

how would one change the script such it looped while not finding the line "start" in the extension.log file with a timeout option.

Additional it should also take into account that the {ver} is not static, and is a semver version "2.3.4" ect, it should take the highest version folder that exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code:

```
#! /bin/bash
timeout=300 #seconds
now=$(date +%s)
let deadline=now+timeout 
log=/tmp/log.txt

while ( [ ! -f "$log" ] || (! grep "Start" $log) )
do
  if [ $(date +%s) -gt "$deadline" ]
  then
    echo "Timeout"
    break
  fi
  echo "Sleeping"
  sleep 3
done

echo "Done waiting"
```

Just change the `log` variable and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're fairly close except BASH syntax issues as condition is not evaluated in `(...)`.

This should work:

```
logfile='/var/log/azure/Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.DockerExtension/{ver}/extension.log'

while ! grep -q "Start" "$logfile"; do
   sleep 5
done

echo "hello world"
```